# table frequencies analysis

Tags: logistic, chi-squared-test, frequency

[image]I am a researcher in cognitive psychology, I have to analyze a set of frequencies in a sample of 30 subjects. Each subject was submitted to 3 different conditions, with 3 different outcomes. In total, for each participant, I have 90 trials, so the data set to enter in SPSS is huge. How can analyze this data? Is it better a logistic regression or a chi-squared? Moreover, is it correct that chi-squared cannot be applied when more of 20 % of the categories has a frequency < 5?

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated.  Please tell us a bit more about your outcomes (is it binary? Continuous? Categorical? Ordinal?) and the nature of the different conditions the subjects were submitted to (is it categorical? Dose-response/Ordinal?).  The short response to your question as it is currently phrased is "it depends on your outcome and what it is you are trying to answer"

Comment: Thanks Marquis, well it is binary and categorical. Participants can decide to perform 3 different actions: fight, flee, nothing. I want to know whether the action they perform, is related with a specific context expressed by the three different conditions.

Comment: I guess I have to perform a chi-squared test, however in SPSS If I want to enter the frequencies and not the data subject by subject, how can I do? is it possible to weigh more than a variable?

Comment: Please edit your question to include more details about your data and the research question.  You also mentioned weighting variables.  What kind of weights are you talking about?  Are you referring to the fact that you have 3 repeated measures on the same subject?  Also, you did not answer my question about the conditions.  I'm assuming they are nominal and not ordinal/show some kind of dose-response.  Is that correct?

Comment: It is a nominal variable. I want to know whether my participants fight, flee or nothing in different conditions repeated on the same subject. I tried to enter the data in SPSS, but it is difficult if you have frequencies and not the datas subject by subject. Are there any other options?

Comment: When you mentioned, "but it is difficult if you have frequencies and not the datas subject by subject," are you saying that you only have aggregated frequencies and not a dataset (i.e. with 90 observations if in "long" format and 30 observations if in "wide" format)?  If so, it might be easier to do the calculations by hand

Comment: do you mean on excel?

Comment: Yes, if you have only aggregates then doing it by hand--or in Excel--may be easier than trying to carry it out in SPSS.  If you do have the raw data, then you should use SPSS for the analysis

Comment: Thanks Marquis, I did on excel. For what concerns the post hoc how do I have to proceed?

Comment: please edit your post to incorporate the additional information you posted in the comments, and include a screenshot of the frequencies table, so then the original post can be a "standalone" document

Comment: Again me, I added my screenshot, the issue is, since the frequencies in 4 out of 9 cells are almost null, does make any sense to apply chi-squared in the control_fight and control_flee conditions? Here, participants nearly always fight in the control_fight condition and flee in the control_flee condition

Comment: can you explain again what the numbers in the cells are?  I was under the impression that each observation represented a single person, but I think I am wrong, unless the cells contain some kind of a score

Comment: In the raw subjects (30), in the columns the frequencies of the fight/flee/late action each participants in the three different conditions.

Comment: Sorry, this is still not clear to me.  For example, what do the numbers 1-30 in column A represent?  Are they person's identifier?  So for example, in row 3, cell B3-D3 are telling me that, under the "control_fight" condition, Person 1's response was "Fight" in 26/30 trials, "Flee" in none of the 30 trials, and "late" in 3/30 trials? In other words, each person went through 30 trials *per condition* and each person's response was recorded for each of the 90 total trials?

Comment: Yes they are the subjects (1,2,3...30). Exactly.

Comment: Can you tell me more about the study design?  Were all 90 trials performed on each subject *on the same day* or were they spaced out over time?  Also, you never answered my question on what your ultimate research question is.  That is, what you are trying to answer and compare between these groups of people.  Are you trying to measure whether a subject changes his/her behavior over time (i.e. maturational trends) or something else?  Again--please edit your original post to include more details about the study design so we can help you

Comment: For example what do "control_fight," "control_flee," and "control_late" refer to?  I understand some scientists hesitate to post their work online if it is a work in progress and the scientist wishes to publish it at some point, but we need more info in order to be able to help you